# How to write integer to a file,.io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: python, csv, input, output

I'm trying to add 1 to the last integer of a file in excel. I can do this as the new_id is correct. However when I try to write the new_id to the file it does not work. Returning the `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error message.`

```py
import csv
ID = []

file = open("customerID.csv","r")

for x in file:
    ID.append(x)

lastid = int(ID[-1])

new_id = (lastid + 1)

file.close
print(lastid)
print (new_id)

file.write (str(new_id))

file.close
```

Answer (score 2):

You opened the file for reading only when you specified `'r'` in `open`. If you want to be able to write, you need to open it for writing. Use either `'a'` if you want to write to the end of the file (appending), or `'w'` if you want to erase the file prior to writing:

```
file = open("customerID.csv", "a")
```

---

Also note, your `file.close` lines aren't doing anything. You need to actually call the `close` method:

```
file.close()  # Note the ()
```

And, you can't use `file` once `close` has been called on it.

Comment: Thanks so much I feel stupid now. I guess it just needed another pair of eyes.